# Creating a wordpress video header on home page only

Tags: video-header

I would like to have an auto-played video on home page only. How to embed media file (mp4) uploaded on server and loads only on home page.

Comment: You could pass a `is_home()` condition within your homepage related files.

Comment: in a slider? or just want to add it through html?

Comment: @Christine -  I'm learning codings myself.... My home.php file been uploaded [here](http://jmp.sh/aLA4WOW). where to add which code.  Kindly share complete snap of the code wanted to plug.

Comment: @ArsalanMithani - I would like to add as html code on home page only. The frontend been uploaded [here](http://jmp.sh/SYQBeQq) and I just need to add the video (without any navigation) on the red ribbon place.

Answer (score 0):

@Owen, There are several ways to do it.

First: You can do it from Backend.

Create a page "home" and add the video from Media button and Choose this page as "Home" from Setting -> Reading --> Static Page

Second: You can create a home page template and put the video Url path in that page manually and display it.

the best way I suggest you use the plugin called "fullpagejs" in that you can create a video slide with auto-played video and map that slide to your home page. this should work very fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Hope the third one helps for me.... I'll try and give feedback....